# Using JavaScript/jQuery to display a "Loading..." popup window that persists between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

A web site I'm working on has a search facility that triggers a "Now searching..." popup window to be displayed as soon as the form is submitted on the first page, and this popup window remains onscreen until the second page has finished loading. This popup window isn't a JavaScript window as such, it's just a layer with a high z-index value set.

The search request is handled using a basic form submit without any AJAX calls or iframes, so how can the popup window still be displayed and persist between page loads? The expected behaviour would be for the browser to unload/remove the first page from memory and just display a blank page until the code for the second page had started to download and was ready to be displayed. Also, this behaviour no longer works when the web site is displayed in Edge so I need to have some understanding of how the popup functionality might work in order to fix the problem in that browser.

Thank you in advance for any advice or assistance. Unfortunately the web site I'm working on is being updated so I cannot link to it at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, it will be easy to use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) with callbacks

```
$.ajax({
    //params like type, data, url etc..
    //...
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    dataType: 'html', //if you will receive HTML from server 
    beforeSend: function() {
      //clear page and show popup
      $("#main").html(""); //for example if your main block has id="main"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      //draw new page
      $("#main").html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check the code and see if beforeSend or something similar is being used. If I access the second page directly (for example, by reloading the page) the popup window is still displayed, so I wonder if all the web site is doing is loading the popup window on both pages and the transition appears to be seamless because the browser doesn't display a blank page in the interim.

Answer (score 1):

There is no true persistence between pages on the internet, for instance when you're 'logged in' to a website, each time you visit a page, you're not still logged in, you just get re logged in by the server passing data from page to page identifying the users session. We can only give the illusion (and practical benefit) of persistence in this manner.

There are ways to create the illusion of what you're asking for, however AJAX is the only solution I'd suggest. When the user submits the form, trigger the loading, then call the page, and upon receiving a successful response display the results to the user.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thank you. I do already use AJAX requests (although admittedly I'm no power user) but the way the web site works seemed non-intuitive precisely because of the fact that there shouldn't be any persistence between pages. I think this is a side-effect of how browsers work, in that the window isn't repainted until the browser has enough data available to start displaying the next page.